# R: naming a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read over 200 CSV files, each with multiple rows and columns of numbers. It makes most sense to reach each one as a separate data frame.

Ideally, I'd like to give meaningful names. So the data frame of store 1, room 1 would be named `store.1.room.1`, and `store.1.room.2`. This would go all the way up to `store.100.room.1`, `store.100.room.2` etc.

I can read each file into a specified data frame. For example:

```
store.1.room.1 <- read.csv(filepath,...)
```

But how do I create a dynamically created data frame name using a For loop?

For example:

```
for (i in 1:100){    
  for (j in 1:2){    
    store.i.room.j <- read.csv(filepath...)    
 }    
}
```

Alternatively, is there another approach that I should consider instead of having each csv file as a separate data frame?

Thanks

Comment: Don't store these as separate variables; put them in a list (or a nested list). Something like `lapply(1:10, function(i) lapply(1:2, function(j) read.table(paste("file",i,j,"csv", sep="."))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I am answering your question, but you would never want to store those CSV files into separate data frames. What I would do in your case is this:

```
set <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:100){
    ##calculate filename here
    current.csv <- read.csv(filename)
    current.csv <- cbind(current.csv, index = i)
    set <- rbind(set, current.csv)
```

An additional column is being used to identify which csv files the measurements are from.

EDIT:

This is useful to apply `tapply` in certain vectors of your `data.frame`. Also, in case you'd like to keep the measurements of only one csv (let's say the one indexed by 5), you can enter

```
single.data.frame <- set[set$index == 5, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your dataframes using `read.csv` as you have above, but store them into a list.  Then give names to each item (i.e. dataframe) in the list:

```
# initialize an empty list
my_list <- list()

for (i in 1:100) {
for (j in 1:2) {
df <- read.csv(filename...)
df_name <- paste("store", i, "room", j, sep="")
my_list[[df_name]] <- df
}
}

# now you can access any data frame you wish by using my_list$store.i.room.j
```

Comment: Thank you. This suggestion solved my problem exactly the way I wanted it.   The one below is helpful as it enables me to analyze the data faster.